# Is stakeholder management listed or inferred?

Tags: management, resume, project-management

I have worked multiple times in technical projects that I was responsible for the successful synchronisation of all parties and update on progress. Basically I managed all the stakeholders.
My question is, do we explicitly state in a resume the term "stakeholder management" as skill and then analyse what we did?
Eg
Job position:

1. Worked on X project
2. Implemented Y project
3. Stakeholder management

Or is stakeholder management inferred from what we say we worked on?

Comment: I think it has a standard meaning related to projects right?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: ^

Comment: @smith What does it mean to you?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie: identifying all important project stakeholders, involving them and keeping them engaged with clear communication and frequent updates

Answer (score 5):

A resume should be result orientated, not task oriented. As a hiring manager I want to know what you achieved not what you did. "Stakeholder management" is a task. "Minimized any stakeholder interference through efficient updates and communication" is a quantitative result.

It's certainly ok to mention stakeholder management, but describe the outcome, not the how. If your management didn't make any positive difference, than leave it out. If it did make a difference, describe what that difference was.

Answer (score 3):

When I interview candidates I always ask what they actually did in the project they list. Unless they are working on a single person project, each team member will contribute in some way to the project, both with hard and soft skills.

One can infer that at team level stakeholder management was done (or not), but if you want to make it visible that you actively contributed to it, it's better to say that explicitly.

Comment: How is that phrased properly in the short space of a resume? An issue that I have is that I don't like to write anything that could be considered as "bragging" if that makes sense. But that is just me

Comment: @smith: Project X, role and responsibilities: stakeholder management,

Comment: That's it? Nothing more?

Comment: @smith, that's the barebone; you can flesh it out more according to your preferences